# Are there practices where Sepharadim do not hold by Shulchan Aruch?

Tags: shulchan-aruch

I remember a Tunisian friend who was fairly learned mentioned a few places (halachically, not geographically) where Sepharadim do not go by the SA, but can't remember the specifics.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68886/are-there-any-cases-where-sephardim-generally-hold-by-the-rema

Comment: Rabbeinu Tam nightfall is the first place to check.

Comment: Sephardim were never a homogeneous group, since at least the 12th century. (Cf. Egyptians, Syrians, Moroccans, Tunisians, etc.)  I am sure that there is some group of Sephardim that follow just about any ruling in the ShA. | Are you asking about the majority of Sephardim?

Comment: Kapparot. See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30254/1865

Comment: Do you mean that they follow Ramma instead? Or that they follow a Rishon not mentioned in Shulchan Aruch?

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/64719

Comment: There are probably few rulings of the sha that some Sephardim haven't disagreed with. There are probably hundreds of answers to this, rendering it too broad.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that Moroccan Jews very often follow Rama. This is not because of an affinity for him in particular, but for Ashkenazim in general, the result of the influence of the Ashkenazi Rosh on Spaniards, followed by their southern migration.

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9E%D7%95_%D7%97 is a good example.

Answer (score 3):

Many Sepharadim uphold the custom of Kapparot to this day despite Maran's objections. See [my answer to this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/31079/2091) for further information.

Comment: Good example. Consider including the objection itself, and an example or two of the "many Sepharadim".

Answer (score 2):

Kedusha - the Shulchan Aruch (Orach Chaim 125) rules that only the parts that the Tzibbur recites is Kadosh Kadosh and Baruch Kvod... The Arizal said that the Tzibbur should recite all of kedusha with the Chazan. The Sephardic Minhag (although this is also followed by Ashkenzim, aside from Briskers, supposedly Yekkes, and interestingly the Yeshiva Beis Yisroel in Neve Yaakov Minhag , and those who follow Minhagei Hagr"a) is to follow the Arizal.

Comment: For one just about no one follows the Ari who only said to say the first two words aloud with the Chazan and the rest in an undertone. Second your categorization of the now-common practice of reciting everything aloud prior to the Chazan as "the Sephardic Minhag" (and the Ashkenazi Minhag!) is weak, considering everyone in Spain/Germany didn't do that for over a thousand years. See Siddur Sefas Yisroel (Yekke) as an example that this is not just the Gra but anyone who cares about following the original Minhag. Plus one could argue the ShA is like the Taz that saying along is merely optional.

Comment: @DoubleAA excuse me. The question is answered, the fact that the Minhag is to follow the Arizal "lechatzain" does detract from the fact that the S"A paskens one way, and the Sephardim do differently. The OP didn't ask for something that Sephardim *exclusively* do not follow the SA

Comment: Again, it's not 100% clear the ShA actually forbids this. He may just hold it's not necessary. Many have argued that so as not to create a Machloket between Rs Karo and Luria (who knew each other). See for instance discussion in Yabia Omer 7:14. This answer oversimplifies/misidentifies R Karo's position, R Luria's position, and who has what custom. It could really use some improvement.

Comment: @DoubleAA thank you I will definitely look into it

Comment: I am Sephardi and our Minhag is like Maran. So not all Sephardim

Comment: @ElShteiger #notall  what type of sefardi are  you

Comment: West European Sefardí. Interestingly, in Mincha Shabbat and Shalosh regalim

Comment: @ElShteiger as in Spanish and Portuguese?

Answer (score 2):

In Hilchot Chabbat (253,4), the SA says that you should not put hot water from a *keli rishon* into an other one. The minhag of the North African Jews is to do that (I heard that from a Tunisian Rav and we could find that in Shout Shemesh Oumaguen T1 s. 8,15,19 and 21 written by Rav Shalom Messas).

For the *hadlakat nerot* (263,5), the minhag of the North African Jews is to bless after the *hadlaka* like the Rama. (Cf Aley Hadass which compilates the Tunisian minhagim)

Comment: By oral witness do you mean that this was related to you by North Africans (that is  perfectly valid source, I just want to clarify). Do you know where in Shemesh Umagen this is discussed? Can you similarly source the N. African practice regarding lighting?

Comment: It is worth mentioning that Moroccan Jews very often follow Rama. This is not because of an affinity for him in particular, but for Ashkenazim in general, the result of the influence of the Ashkenazi Rosh on Spaniards, followed by their southern migration.

Comment: @mevaqesh : I'm Tunisian and I heard that from a Tunisian Rav. For the lighting, it's appear in the book Aley Hadass which compilates a lot of Tunisian minhagim. For the Rav Messas I found those references : Tevouot Shemesh OH 26, Shemesh Oumaguen T1 s. 8,15,19 and 21

Comment: I took the liberty of editing some of your comments into the post. Important info. like sources should be mentioned in the actual post; not in comments.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding wearing a watch with teffilin on . The Shulchan Aruch 27:4 writes one shouldnt wear anything that makes a sepration between the teffilin. However,the Rama there notes that only os talking in a case of the batim not the arm or hand. The Sefardim seem to be maikel(Yacve Daas- Chacham Ovadia) while the Ashkenazim are machmir.

Comment: Could you source the YD?

Comment: Who says the ShA disagrees with the Rama?

Comment: Does anyone know why Rav Ovadia doesnt follow the Maran on this?

Comment: @doubleAA,if you see the Bais Yosef you see he goes through the Machlokes of the Rosh and the Rashbah,and we see the SA still paskens like the Rosh

Answer (score 1):

-- Ovadia Yosef zt”l and many other poskim rule that a blind man can receive an aliyah, in contradiction to the Shulchan Aruch.

http://halachayomit.co.il/en/ReadHalacha.aspx?HalachaID=4487

-- One does not recite a second blessing when putting a tallit back on after having removed it for as short time.

Discussed here as a side note to a different question on mezuzah:

http://halachayomit.co.il/en/ReadHalacha.aspx?HalachaID=3240

*"Although in general we follow all of the rulings of Maran Ha’Shulchan Aruch, Maran Ha’Chida writes that in instances such as these where many Poskim disagree with Maran, we must be concerned with the prohibition of reciting a blessing in vain even in opposition of Maran’s ruling. Thus, halachically speaking, as long as one had in mind originally to wear the Tallit again soon after removing it, one does not recite another blessing."*

I definitely remember a few more of these including one with the statement "If Maran HaShulchan Aruch had only had this source in front of him, surely he would have ruled X."

Answer (score 0):

Whenever there is a machloket between the arizal and the SA we go after the arizal (see the peticha of ohr letzion)

Comment: Who is 'we'? [Char]

Comment: We sephardim it is an accepted opinion by most major sephardic poskim that we we will ho after the arizal over the SA besides for rav ovadia yosef

Comment: Sephardim are not historically a homogeneous group. Please specify which sub set of Sephardim you are referring to.

Comment: In general, for another user to be informed of your comments, you should include his username in the comment with a @ in front of it, like @mevaqesh

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27710)

Comment: @sabbahillel Why isn't it an answer?